# What is the difference of the String property accessors?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the difference of String property accessors in JavaScript?

I can create an object with using String property names like;

```
let obj = {"id": 134, "name": "objectsname"}

let obj2 = {id: 134, name: "objectsname"}
```

We can access both objects properties;

```
console.log(obj.name);  //prints "objectsname"

console.log(obj.name);  //prints "objectsname"
```

What is the difference between obj and obj2?

Comment: Nothing at all. Once interpreted, they're identical. Object keys are strings (or Symbols) regardless.

Comment: it is just a different object with the same key/value pairs.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Why every tutorial doesn't mentions about String property accessors? Why everbody trying to not to use it?

Comment: Because less syntax noise is a good thing - if you don't have to use `"`, might as well avoid it. It adds no information of value - only use it when you have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in your examples. However when your object key contains some special characters you need to wrap it with quotes. For example:

```
 // invalid
 const a = {^name: 1} // SyntaxError: expected property name, got '^'

 // valid
 const a = {"^name": 1}

 // valid
 const a = {}
 a["^name"] = 1
```